# Browsing OneDrive folders with Explorer on Windows 11 Slow

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, onedrive

Browsing folders that are synced by OneDrive is extremely slow. Every navigation action takes a 10+ second delay, even if the folder is empty. I found a similar issue description on the [Microsoft Forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-explorer-very-slow-when-entering-onedrive/21abb6c0-7d8d-4bef-a3c0-50e4a542d8ad) without fix.
Common is that the issue occurs since the upgrade to Windows 11. When monitoring Explorer I noticed that during the delay a massive amount of registry queries is performed by explorer in the **HKCU\Software\Classes\** space.
[See Screenshort Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htx6O.png)

Strange is that when navigating the same folders using the tree on the left part of Windows Explorer screen the issue doesn't occur. Same for file open/save dialogues, they don't suffer from the performance issue.

I have already tried enabling the old Ribbon in Windows explorer without any success.

Running latest version of OneDrive (22.248.1127.0001)

Anyone who has a solution to this issue?

Comment: Do you have DropBox or some other sync client loaded as well as OneDrive?

Comment: No, did that check as well.

Comment: Does it happen when Explorer is at full-screen?

Comment: Yes, full screen doesn't resolve the issue. Neither does reverting back to the ribbon bar.
I also checked if there isn't any photo/image related software installed. Only Paint.NET but I did not find any integration issues with that.

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe Mode with Network?

Comment: That I will need to check. Not even sure if OneDrive functions in Safe Mode. Also not sure what the outcome would mean if it does work.

Comment: Did the test in Safe mode with Networking and the issue is still present.

Comment: Have the same problem after latest update. And nothing fixes it. Tried reinstalling all cloud apps, reinstalling windows, everything. If there are cloud apps, then explorer will work slow for those cloud folders. No way around it. Except switch to some better OS.

Did you find any solution to this? In Sep 2023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve the issue by uninstalling OneDrive, removing all OneDrive Application and Data folders from the computer using the following script.

```
:: Removing remaining OneDrive folders.
rd "%UserProfile%\OneDrive" /s /q
rd "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\OneDrive" /s /q
rd "%LocalAppData%\OneDrive" /s /q
rd "%ProgramData%\Microsoft OneDrive" /s /q
rd "%systemdrive%\OneDriveTemp" /s /q

:: Removing remaining  OneDrive registry keys.
REG DELETE "HKCR\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" /f
REG DELETE "HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}" /f
REG DELETE "HKCR\Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive" /f
```

Did a reinstall of latest OneDrive version with /allusers parameter.

After configuration and syncing OneDrive I started adding also SharePoint folders that I was syncing. Initially it looked ok, but after a number of folders the issue is back again. Will continue to zoom in on what SharePoint location is causing the issue. Maybe removing them one by one is enough to solve the issue and track down the root cause...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Was having the exact problem since the last couple days. It seems that File Explorer doesn't like when there are other third-party cloud storage integrations on it. So, I ended up deleting iCloud Drive to check if it will fix the problem. After restarting, the lag goes away. I was using both iCloud and OneDrive on file explorer since a few months and didn't had any problem until very recently. Maybe only Microsoft can figure out what exactly triggers this.

Comment: I have no other sync software running then OneDrive. I do have multiple OneDrive instances running as I am also syncing another corporate OneDrive. I will try to remove that one to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Nope, that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Floris It's a weird bug. Sorry it didn't work for you. I also have a second onedrive instance of my School account added to file explorer but that's not causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is relevant now:

After:

[2023-07 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5028254)] from 28.07.2023

the system works again without any problems. OneDrive files are available again without any time delay and syncing problem.

Comment: For me the issue is still there with last 22H2 update KB5030310. Is there solution for this?